# Issue with jQuery delegate/trigger on :input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I seem to be having an issue delegating a custom event to a set of elements and then trigger that same event.  I'm using jQuery 1.6.  I am selecting a set of :input elements from a form, and having a custom `attrToggle` event be delegated to the form's containing element.  Later on I try to `trigger('attrToggle')` after selecting those same `:input` elements and it doesn't appear as if the handler is getting triggered.

I have created a jsfiddle of a simplified example of this functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/VZHw2/1/

Comment: btw, since you're using jQuery 1.6, use `.prop("disabled",true")` instead of `.attr("disabled",true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, handlers attached to a disabled element can't be triggered. You must enable the element first.